# How is it possible to rank variables using Likert scale?

Tags: regression, spss, ordinal-data, likert

I have a questionnaire of a 3-point Likert scale for an overall evaluation for a service, and several detailed attributes evaluation of that service. For example:
Overall Evaluation (1-3), then
Cleanliness (1-3)
Comfort (1-3)
Privacy (1-3)
..etc
I am looking for a way to find what are the most important variables (attributes) that have the highest impact on overall evaluation.
Is ordinary regression helping?

Answer (score 1):

Normally data from such Likert scales are interpreted as holding ordinal but not interval scaled information, and the linearity assumption in standard linear regression will be problematic for sure with a response variable that only has 3 output values (it may be OK with Likert explanatory variables but then it may not, depending on the data).

There's [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) for response variables that are ordinal. This normally assumes that the explanatory variables are quantitative. You can run it with ordinal x-variables and check whether the implied linear assumption looks OK. Another option is [ordinal-ordinal regression](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-018-9842-2).